# dplyr "not a promise" error

Tags: r, promise, dplyr

I have a panel dataset for which I have created lagged variables using the lag() function.
When I try to calculate the delta for each timepoint, using the mutate command below, I get the error message "Error: not a promise"

```
> kw.lags[,c("imps", "lag1_imps", "lag2_imps")]
Source: local data frame [157,737 x 3]
Groups: 

   imps lag1_imps lag2_imps
1    65        NA        NA
2    79        65        NA
3    62        79        65
4    69        62        79
5     1        NA        NA
6     2        NA        NA
7     2         2        NA
8     1         2         2
9     2         1         2
10    5        NA        NA
..  ...       ...       ...

> kw.deltas <- mutate(kw.lags, 
+   d1_imps = imps - lag1_imps,
+   d2_imps = imps - lag2_imps,
+   d3_imps = imps - lag3_imps,
+ )
Error: not a promise
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you promote this to an issue on github. https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues?state=open

Comment: There's no lag3_imps in your data frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a comma after the last line in your mutate statement. Try to remove that, and see if it fixes the error.

Comment: This does, in fact, appear to be the root of the problem.  I believe dplyr has been changed or will soon be changed so that it does not throw an error in this situation.